# Unable to install r-base newer than 3.3.1 using conda

Tags: python, r, installation, conda

I am trying to install `r-base` (and other r packages) using `conda`. But it keeps throwing version 3.3.1 my way.

I have tried `r-essentials` from `conda-forge`, `r` channels. Already updated `conda`.

I use macOS Catalina 10.15.5

```
% conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : /Users/user/anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /Users/user/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/user/.condarc
          conda version : 4.8.3
    conda-build version : 3.19.2
         python version : 3.7.6.final.0
       virtual packages : __osx=10.15.5
       base environment : /Users/user/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/osx-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /Users/user/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/user/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/user/anaconda3/envs
                          /Users/user/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.8.3 requests/2.24.0 CPython/3.7.6 Darwin/19.5.0 OSX/10.15.5
                UID:GID : 502:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False




% conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 r-base

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/user/anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - r-base


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    _r-mutex-1.0.1             |      anacondar_1           3 KB  conda-forge/label/cf202003
    ca-certificates-2019.11.28 |       hecc5488_0         145 KB  conda-forge/label/cf202003
    certifi-2019.11.28         |   py37hc8dfbb8_1         148 KB  conda-forge/label/cf202003
    conda-4.8.3                |   py37hc8dfbb8_1         3.0 MB  conda-forge/label/cf202003
    gsl-2.1                    |                2         2.1 MB  conda-forge/label/cf202003
    libgcc-4.8.5               |      hdbeacc1_10         302 KB  conda-forge/label/cf202003
    r-base-3.3.1               |                0        45.3 MB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        51.0 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  _r-mutex           conda-forge/label/cf202003/noarch::_r-mutex-1.0.1-anacondar_1
  gsl                conda-forge/label/cf202003/osx-64::gsl-2.1-2
  libgcc             conda-forge/label/cf202003/osx-64::libgcc-4.8.5-hdbeacc1_10
  r-base             pkgs/r/osx-64::r-base-3.3.1-0

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  ca-certificates    conda-forge::ca-certificates-2020.6.2~ --> conda-forge/label/cf202003::ca-certificates-2019.11.28-hecc5488_0
  certifi            conda-forge::certifi-2020.6.20-py37hc~ --> conda-forge/label/cf202003::certifi-2019.11.28-py37hc8dfbb8_1
  conda                                         conda-forge --> conda-forge/label/cf202003
```

```
% conda install -c conda-forge r-essentials         
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/sainis8/anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - r-essentials


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    _r-mutex-1.0.1             |      anacondar_1           3 KB  conda-forge
    gsl-2.1                    |                2         2.1 MB  conda-forge
    libgcc-4.8.5               |      hdbeacc1_10         302 KB  conda-forge
    r-3.3.1                    |         r3.3.1_0          914 B
    r-assertthat-0.1           |         r3.3.1_4          43 KB
    r-base-3.3.1               |                0        45.3 MB
    r-base64enc-0.1_3          |         r3.3.1_0          23 KB
    r-bh-1.60.0_2              |         r3.3.1_0         8.2 MB  bioconda
    r-bitops-1.0_6             |         r3.3.1_2          20 KB
    r-boot-1.3_18              |         r3.3.1_0         558 KB
    r-car-2.1_4                |         r3.3.1_0         1.4 MB  bioconda
    r-caret-6.0_70             |         r3.3.1_0         4.5 MB
    r-catools-1.17.1           |         r3.3.1_1         158 KB  bioconda
    r-class-7.3_14             |         r3.3.1_0          78 KB
    r-cluster-2.0.4            |         r3.3.1_0         452 KB
    r-codetools-0.2_14         |         r3.3.1_0          44 KB
    r-colorspace-1.2_6         |         r3.3.1_0         348 KB
    r-crayon-1.3.1             |         r3.3.1_0         587 KB
    r-curl-0.9.7               |         r3.3.1_0         252 KB
    r-data.table-1.10.0        |         r3.3.1_1         1.1 MB  bioconda
    r-dbi-0.4_1                |         r3.3.1_0         199 KB
    r-dichromat-2.0_0          |         r3.3.1_2         143 KB
    r-digest-0.6.9             |         r3.3.1_0          97 KB
    r-dplyr-0.5.0              |         r3.3.1_1         1.5 MB  bioconda
    r-essentials-1.4.3         |         r3.3.1_0           2 KB
    r-evaluate-0.9             |         r3.3.1_0          40 KB
    r-foreach-1.4.3            |         r3.3.1_0         360 KB
    r-foreign-0.8_66           |         r3.3.1_0         203 KB
    r-formatr-1.4              |         r3.3.1_0          44 KB
    r-ggplot2-2.2.1            |         r3.3.1_0         2.7 MB  bioconda
    r-gistr-0.3.6              |         r3.3.1_0         1.2 MB
    r-glmnet-2.0_5             |         r3.3.1_0         1.5 MB
    r-gtable-0.2.0             |         r3.3.1_0          56 KB
    r-hexbin-1.27.1            |         r3.3.1_0         735 KB
    r-highr-0.6                |         r3.3.1_0          29 KB
    r-htmltools-0.3.5          |         r3.3.1_0         116 KB
    r-htmlwidgets-0.6          |         r3.3.1_0         385 KB
    r-httpuv-1.3.3             |         r3.3.1_0         284 KB
    r-httr-1.2.0               |         r3.3.1_0         254 KB
    r-irdisplay-0.4.3          |         r3.3.1_2          26 KB
    r-irkernel-0.7             |         r3.3.1_2         102 KB
    r-iterators-1.0.8          |         r3.3.1_0         297 KB
    r-jsonlite-0.9.22          |         r3.3.1_0         565 KB
    r-kernsmooth-2.23_15       |         r3.3.1_0          76 KB
    r-knitr-1.12.3             |         r3.3.1_0         677 KB  bioconda
    r-labeling-0.3             |         r3.3.1_2          39 KB
    r-lattice-0.20_33          |         r3.3.1_0         671 KB
    r-lazyeval-0.2.0           |         r3.3.1_0         108 KB
    r-lme4-1.1_12              |         r3.3.1_0         4.1 MB
    r-magrittr-1.5             |         r3.3.1_2         151 KB
    r-maps-3.1.0               |         r3.3.1_0         2.5 MB
    r-markdown-0.7.7           |         r3.3.1_2          96 KB
    r-mass-7.3_45              |         r3.3.1_0         991 KB
    r-matrix-1.2_6             |         r3.3.1_0         2.8 MB
    r-matrixmodels-0.4_1       |         r3.3.1_0         217 KB
    r-memoise-1.0.0            |         r3.3.1_0          22 KB
    r-mgcv-1.8_12              |         r3.3.1_0         1.9 MB
    r-mime-0.4                 |         r3.3.1_0          24 KB
    r-minqa-1.2.4              |         r3.3.1_2          95 KB
    r-munsell-0.4.3            |         r3.3.1_0         125 KB
    r-nlme-3.1_128             |         r3.3.1_0         2.0 MB
    r-nloptr-1.0.4             |         r3.3.1_2         519 KB
    r-nnet-7.3_12              |         r3.3.1_0          92 KB
    r-openssl-0.9.4            |         r3.3.1_0         508 KB
    r-pbdzmq-0.2_3             |         r3.3.1_0         339 KB
    r-pbkrtest-0.4_6           |         r3.3.1_0         205 KB
    r-plyr-1.8.4               |         r3.3.1_0         711 KB
    r-pryr-0.1.2               |         r3.3.1_0         172 KB
    r-quantmod-0.4_5           |         r3.3.1_2         455 KB
    r-quantreg-5.26            |         r3.3.1_0         1.7 MB
    r-r6-2.1.2                 |         r3.3.1_0         214 KB
    r-randomforest-4.6_12      |         r3.3.1_0         135 KB
    r-rbokeh-0.4.2             |         r3.3.1_0         1.1 MB
    r-rcolorbrewer-1.1_2       |         r3.3.1_3          27 KB
    r-rcpp-0.12.5              |         r3.3.1_0         2.0 MB
    r-rcppeigen-0.3.2.8.1      |         r3.3.1_0         1.3 MB
    r-recommended-3.3.1        |         r3.3.1_0           1 KB
    r-repr-0.7                 |         r3.3.1_0          54 KB
    r-reshape2-1.4.1           |         r3.3.1_2          92 KB
    r-rmarkdown-0.9.6          |         r3.3.1_0         1.5 MB
    r-rpart-4.1_10             |         r3.3.1_0         831 KB
    r-scales-0.4.1             |         r3.3.1_1         204 KB  bioconda
    r-shiny-0.13.2             |         r3.3.1_0         1.8 MB
    r-sparsem-1.7              |         r3.3.1_0         624 KB
    r-spatial-7.3_11           |         r3.3.1_0         115 KB
    r-stringi-1.1.1            |         r3.3.1_0         9.1 MB
    r-stringr-1.1.0            |         r3.3.1_0         113 KB  bioconda
    r-survival-2.39_4          |         r3.3.1_0         4.4 MB
    r-tibble-1.2               |         r3.3.1_1         132 KB  bioconda
    r-tidyr-0.5.1              |         r3.3.1_0         335 KB
    r-ttr-0.23_1               |         r3.3.1_0         397 KB
    r-uuid-0.1_2               |         r3.3.1_0          16 KB
    r-xtable-1.8_2             |         r3.3.1_0         671 KB
    r-xts-0.9_7                |         r3.3.1_2         580 KB
    r-yaml-2.1.13              |         r3.3.1_2          77 KB
    r-zoo-1.7_13               |         r3.3.1_0         835 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:       123.6 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  _r-mutex           conda-forge/noarch::_r-mutex-1.0.1-anacondar_1
  gsl                conda-forge/osx-64::gsl-2.1-2
  libgcc             conda-forge/osx-64::libgcc-4.8.5-hdbeacc1_10
  r                  pkgs/r/osx-64::r-3.3.1-r3.3.1_0
  r-assertthat       pkgs/r/osx-64::r-assertthat-0.1-r3.3.1_4
  r-base             pkgs/r/osx-64::r-base-3.3.1-0
  r-base64enc        pkgs/r/osx-64::r-base64enc-0.1_3-r3.3.1_0
  r-bh               bioconda/osx-64::r-bh-1.60.0_2-r3.3.1_0
  r-bitops           pkgs/r/osx-64::r-bitops-1.0_6-r3.3.1_2
  r-boot             pkgs/r/osx-64::r-boot-1.3_18-r3.3.1_0
  r-car              bioconda/osx-64::r-car-2.1_4-r3.3.1_0
  r-caret            pkgs/r/osx-64::r-caret-6.0_70-r3.3.1_0
  r-catools          bioconda/osx-64::r-catools-1.17.1-r3.3.1_1
  r-class            pkgs/r/osx-64::r-class-7.3_14-r3.3.1_0
  r-cluster          pkgs/r/osx-64::r-cluster-2.0.4-r3.3.1_0
  r-codetools        pkgs/r/osx-64::r-codetools-0.2_14-r3.3.1_0
  r-colorspace       pkgs/r/osx-64::r-colorspace-1.2_6-r3.3.1_0
  r-crayon           pkgs/r/osx-64::r-crayon-1.3.1-r3.3.1_0
  r-curl             pkgs/r/osx-64::r-curl-0.9.7-r3.3.1_0
  r-data.table       bioconda/osx-64::r-data.table-1.10.0-r3.3.1_1
  r-dbi              pkgs/r/osx-64::r-dbi-0.4_1-r3.3.1_0
  r-dichromat        pkgs/r/osx-64::r-dichromat-2.0_0-r3.3.1_2
  r-digest           pkgs/r/osx-64::r-digest-0.6.9-r3.3.1_0
  r-dplyr            bioconda/osx-64::r-dplyr-0.5.0-r3.3.1_1
  r-essentials       pkgs/r/osx-64::r-essentials-1.4.3-r3.3.1_0
  r-evaluate         pkgs/r/osx-64::r-evaluate-0.9-r3.3.1_0
  r-foreach          pkgs/r/osx-64::r-foreach-1.4.3-r3.3.1_0
  r-foreign          pkgs/r/osx-64::r-foreign-0.8_66-r3.3.1_0
  r-formatr          pkgs/r/osx-64::r-formatr-1.4-r3.3.1_0
  r-ggplot2          bioconda/osx-64::r-ggplot2-2.2.1-r3.3.1_0
  r-gistr            pkgs/r/osx-64::r-gistr-0.3.6-r3.3.1_0
  r-glmnet           pkgs/r/osx-64::r-glmnet-2.0_5-r3.3.1_0
  r-gtable           pkgs/r/osx-64::r-gtable-0.2.0-r3.3.1_0
  r-hexbin           pkgs/r/osx-64::r-hexbin-1.27.1-r3.3.1_0
  r-highr            pkgs/r/osx-64::r-highr-0.6-r3.3.1_0
  r-htmltools        pkgs/r/osx-64::r-htmltools-0.3.5-r3.3.1_0
  r-htmlwidgets      pkgs/r/osx-64::r-htmlwidgets-0.6-r3.3.1_0
  r-httpuv           pkgs/r/osx-64::r-httpuv-1.3.3-r3.3.1_0
  r-httr             pkgs/r/osx-64::r-httr-1.2.0-r3.3.1_0
  r-irdisplay        pkgs/r/osx-64::r-irdisplay-0.4.3-r3.3.1_2
  r-irkernel         pkgs/r/osx-64::r-irkernel-0.7-r3.3.1_2
  r-iterators        pkgs/r/osx-64::r-iterators-1.0.8-r3.3.1_0
  r-jsonlite         pkgs/r/osx-64::r-jsonlite-0.9.22-r3.3.1_0
  r-kernsmooth       pkgs/r/osx-64::r-kernsmooth-2.23_15-r3.3.1_0
  r-knitr            bioconda/osx-64::r-knitr-1.12.3-r3.3.1_0
  r-labeling         pkgs/r/osx-64::r-labeling-0.3-r3.3.1_2
  r-lattice          pkgs/r/osx-64::r-lattice-0.20_33-r3.3.1_0
  r-lazyeval         pkgs/r/osx-64::r-lazyeval-0.2.0-r3.3.1_0
  r-lme4             pkgs/r/osx-64::r-lme4-1.1_12-r3.3.1_0
  r-magrittr         pkgs/r/osx-64::r-magrittr-1.5-r3.3.1_2
  r-maps             pkgs/r/osx-64::r-maps-3.1.0-r3.3.1_0
  r-markdown         pkgs/r/osx-64::r-markdown-0.7.7-r3.3.1_2
  r-mass             pkgs/r/osx-64::r-mass-7.3_45-r3.3.1_0
  r-matrix           pkgs/r/osx-64::r-matrix-1.2_6-r3.3.1_0
  r-matrixmodels     pkgs/r/osx-64::r-matrixmodels-0.4_1-r3.3.1_0
  r-memoise          pkgs/r/osx-64::r-memoise-1.0.0-r3.3.1_0
  r-mgcv             pkgs/r/osx-64::r-mgcv-1.8_12-r3.3.1_0
  r-mime             pkgs/r/osx-64::r-mime-0.4-r3.3.1_0
  r-minqa            pkgs/r/osx-64::r-minqa-1.2.4-r3.3.1_2
  r-munsell          pkgs/r/osx-64::r-munsell-0.4.3-r3.3.1_0
  r-nlme             pkgs/r/osx-64::r-nlme-3.1_128-r3.3.1_0
  r-nloptr           pkgs/r/osx-64::r-nloptr-1.0.4-r3.3.1_2
  r-nnet             pkgs/r/osx-64::r-nnet-7.3_12-r3.3.1_0
  r-openssl          pkgs/r/osx-64::r-openssl-0.9.4-r3.3.1_0
  r-pbdzmq           pkgs/r/osx-64::r-pbdzmq-0.2_3-r3.3.1_0
  r-pbkrtest         pkgs/r/osx-64::r-pbkrtest-0.4_6-r3.3.1_0
  r-plyr             pkgs/r/osx-64::r-plyr-1.8.4-r3.3.1_0
  r-pryr             pkgs/r/osx-64::r-pryr-0.1.2-r3.3.1_0
  r-quantmod         pkgs/r/osx-64::r-quantmod-0.4_5-r3.3.1_2
  r-quantreg         pkgs/r/osx-64::r-quantreg-5.26-r3.3.1_0
  r-r6               pkgs/r/osx-64::r-r6-2.1.2-r3.3.1_0
  r-randomforest     pkgs/r/osx-64::r-randomforest-4.6_12-r3.3.1_0
  r-rbokeh           pkgs/r/osx-64::r-rbokeh-0.4.2-r3.3.1_0
  r-rcolorbrewer     pkgs/r/osx-64::r-rcolorbrewer-1.1_2-r3.3.1_3
  r-rcpp             pkgs/r/osx-64::r-rcpp-0.12.5-r3.3.1_0
  r-rcppeigen        pkgs/r/osx-64::r-rcppeigen-0.3.2.8.1-r3.3.1_0
  r-recommended      pkgs/r/osx-64::r-recommended-3.3.1-r3.3.1_0
  r-repr             pkgs/r/osx-64::r-repr-0.7-r3.3.1_0
  r-reshape2         pkgs/r/osx-64::r-reshape2-1.4.1-r3.3.1_2
  r-rmarkdown        pkgs/r/osx-64::r-rmarkdown-0.9.6-r3.3.1_0
  r-rpart            pkgs/r/osx-64::r-rpart-4.1_10-r3.3.1_0
  r-scales           bioconda/osx-64::r-scales-0.4.1-r3.3.1_1
  r-shiny            pkgs/r/osx-64::r-shiny-0.13.2-r3.3.1_0
  r-sparsem          pkgs/r/osx-64::r-sparsem-1.7-r3.3.1_0
  r-spatial          pkgs/r/osx-64::r-spatial-7.3_11-r3.3.1_0
  r-stringi          pkgs/r/osx-64::r-stringi-1.1.1-r3.3.1_0
  r-stringr          bioconda/osx-64::r-stringr-1.1.0-r3.3.1_0
  r-survival         pkgs/r/osx-64::r-survival-2.39_4-r3.3.1_0
  r-tibble           bioconda/osx-64::r-tibble-1.2-r3.3.1_1
  r-tidyr            pkgs/r/osx-64::r-tidyr-0.5.1-r3.3.1_0
  r-ttr              pkgs/r/osx-64::r-ttr-0.23_1-r3.3.1_0
  r-uuid             pkgs/r/osx-64::r-uuid-0.1_2-r3.3.1_0
  r-xtable           pkgs/r/osx-64::r-xtable-1.8_2-r3.3.1_0
  r-xts              pkgs/r/osx-64::r-xts-0.9_7-r3.3.1_2
  r-yaml             pkgs/r/osx-64::r-yaml-2.1.13-r3.3.1_2
  r-zoo              pkgs/r/osx-64::r-zoo-1.7_13-r3.3.1_0
```

Comment: Try not installing in the **base** env. I.e., `conda create -n my_r_env -c conda-forge r-essentials`.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten the same issue even recently. I found it's because you have `channel_priority` = `strict`. When you remove that config and go back to the default `flexible` the problem disappears. You don't typically need `strict` anymore, supposedly from what conda devs have written on GitHub it's only needed if trouble solving deps with older packages.